# Is this a closure or something different?

Tags: javascript, function, object, closures

I came across this function about module patterns while I was learning about closures earlier, from what I understand this feels like a closure as Salary is still in scope with the method thats returned with the object but are the other variables still in scope as a closure e.g. name and age or are they destroyed once the object is returned? I thought that because the object references those variables then maybe all the variables are kept alive as part of the closure but not sure.

```
function EmployeeDetails() {
  var name: "Mayank";
  var age = 30;
  var designation = "Developer",
  var salary = 10000;

  var calculateBonus = function(amount) {
    salary = salary + amount;
  }

  return {
    name: name,
    age: age,
    designation: designation,
    calculateBonus: calculateBonus
  }
}

var newEmployee = EmployeeDetails()

var userName = newEmployee.calculateBonus(1000);
```

Comment: Still in what scope? If you call this as a method it runs and it exits.

Comment: So a closure is where an inner function/object has a reference to the outer parent as I understand. in this case does the returned object maintain a reference to all the variables in the scope of EmployeeDetails function? if the question isn't making sense, to put it a different way would you say there is any closure being applied in the code above and if so which bits? thanks, just trying to understand closures better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In terms of where the closure is :-**

Here `calculateBonus` is the function which ultimately closes over `salary` and that's it. Since neither of `name`,`age` and `designation` are being used inside `calculateBonus`, the JavaScript Engine will optimize them out of the closure.

**The following bit has nothing to do with closure :-**

They (`name`,`age` and `designation`) are copied as properties of a new object that you returned explicitly from the `EmployeeDetails` function. So even if you change, say, `newEmployee.name = 'Frank'`, you're just changing the property `name` on that object and not the `name` that was declared inside the `EmployeeDetails` function. That inside `name` is lost once that object got returned because it was a variable that stayed local to this function and didn't get closed over (precisely, used inside) by any other function.

**The interesting bit :-**

As per the Spec on which JS is based, the internal function (`calculateBonus`) technically closes over all the variables of it's outer scope irrespective of whether they are used or not used inside that function but the JS engines are smart enough to detect that and optimize them out of the closure.